# Solving $x^2 + \log_{10}(2x) = 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

On Puzzling Stack Exchange, I saw the following question (now closed):

> Solve
> $$x^2 + \log_{10}(2x) = 3$$

An answer was given:  $\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}$

I agree that the answer is correct, but I don’t see how you would derive it.

Is there a method for solving equations that involve a log and powers of x?

Comment: Have a look at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function for this kind of equation.

Comment: Show that the LHS is an increasing function, and so there is a unique answer which you found by observation. (Though it doesn't explain how to "derive" it other than by guessing intelligently)

Comment: Hi everyone! Each of the answers has received down-votes. Could anyone else who decides to down-vote explain please? None of the down-voters, as far as I can tell, has seen fit to comment as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Extended comment.** In general, such an equation cannot be solved exactly (using elementary functions), but suppose the answer is "nice"; that is, $x = \frac{10^q}{2}$ with $q$ rational. Then

$$
\frac{10^{2q}}{4}+q = 3
$$

or

$$
10^r+2r = 12
$$

with $r = 2q$. This makes $r = 1$ and therefore $q = 1/2$ a particularly appealing guess (which of course works), but even without that piece of luck, we can still constrain $r > 9/10$, since the left-hand side is increasing in $r$ and

$$
10^{9/10} = \sqrt[10]{10^9} < \sqrt[10]{2^{30}} = 2^3 = 8
$$

and similarly $r < 11/10$, since

$$
10^{11/10} = \frac{100}{10^{9/10}} > \frac{100}{8} > 12
$$

so we are looking for a number between $9/10$ and $11/10$.

Answer (score 1):

Add some details to the answer of Thomas Ahle and check it is valid

For the transform $y^2 + \log_{10}(cy) = d$ to $x^2 + \log(a x) = b$:

let $x = y\sqrt{log 10} $,
$$y^2 + \log_{10}(cy)=d$$
$$x^2 + \log(\frac{c}{\sqrt{log 10}} \cdot y)=d\cdot log 10$$

So $a=\frac{c}{\sqrt{log 10}}$ and $b=d\cdot log 10$

The solution of $x^2 + \log(a x) = b$ in the answer of Thomas Ahle is
$x = \sqrt{W(2 e^{2b} a^{-2})/2}$.

For $x^2 + \log_{10}(2x) = 3$:

Let c=2, d=3, so $a=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{log 10}}$, $b=3log 10$

then $a^{-2}=\dfrac{log 10}{4}$, $e^{2b}=e^{6log 10}=10^6$

Sub. to the solution $x = \sqrt{W(2 e^{2b} a^{-2})/2}$,

$W(2 e^{2b} a^{-2})=W(\dfrac{10^6}{2}\cdot log10)=W(10^5 \cdot log 10^5) = log 10^5 = 5$.

So $x = \sqrt{W(2 e^{2b} a^{-2})/2}=\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{2}}$

Answer (score 0):

We can solve general "equations that involve a log and powers of x" by reducing them to the form $x e^x = c$ and using the Lambert W function.

Consider as an example the equation:

$$x^2 + \log(a x) = b.$$
Substitute $y=x^2$,
$$b = y + \log(a y^{1/2})$$
Take exp
$$e^b = e^y (a y^{1/2})$$
Square
$$e^{2b} = e^{2y} a^2 y$$
Replace $y$ by $z/2$ and move $a$ to the $b$ lhs:
$$2 e^{2b} a^{-2} = e^{z} z$$
Now we can use the Lambert W function, which is defined as the solution by $e^y y = x$.
So the solution is
$$z = W(2 e^{2b} a^{-2})$$
And we have $x=\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{z/2}$, so
$$x = \sqrt{W(2 e^{2b} a^{-2})/2}.$$

As you can see below, while Mathematica can't directly solve the original equation, the numerical methods agree with the Lambert W solution: [image]

Comment: this log is with base 10, not e

Comment: @Tim Just use that $\log_{10}(x)=\log_e(x)/\log_e(10)$. The calculations can be done much the same way. The question was just about "solving equations that involve a log and powers of x?" I think the reductions I've shown here give a pretty good idea how one might go about that?

Comment: Yes, I can transform the equation of log with base 10 back to your equation and use your solution to get an answer.

Comment: I do not give you the downvote. But the input and answer you use in Mathematica are wrong?

Comment: @Tim I just made up some arbitrary values for a and b to test that my derivation was correct. I didn't try to match the example you gave in the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

As noticed in the comments, we can proceed numerically showing that there exists only one real solution or by [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) which solve $we^w=z$ in $w$ for a given $z$.

To reduce to this form we can proceed as follows

$$x^2 + \log_{10}(2x) = 3\iff 2x^2 + \log_{10}(4x^2) = 6 \iff 4x^210^{2x^2}=10^6$$

$$4x^2e^{2x^2\log 10}=10^6 \iff (2x^2\log 10)e^{(2x^2\log 10)}=\frac{10^6\log 10}{2}$$

and by $2x^2\log 10=w$

$$we^{w}=\frac{10^6\log10}2$$

---

Note that

$$x^2 + \log_{10}(2x) = 3 \iff 4x^2 +2\; \log_{10}(4x^2)=10 +2$$

from which we can "easily" see that the solution is

$$4x^2=10 \implies x=\sqrt{\frac 5 2}$$